# Two variables from different structs give me a compiling error when I match them

Tags: c++, c, struct

So I might be missing a key point because I've never been good with structs.

I have a struct like this:

```
 typedef struct Message
{
 int  op;           
 char local[128];   
 char remote[128];
int  port;   
} Mensaje;
```

And so I am setting values of this struct like this:
     Mensaje mensaje;
     mensaje.op=htonl(2);

And now I want to get the info from one struct and put it into another, so I can send it.
I try this:

```
 mensaje2.remote=mensaje1.remote;
```

And I get this error: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[128]' from type 'char *'

And it absolutly baffles me, because both things come from the same struct. I've been trying messing with the operator -> but without success.

What should I do so that one struct, without values (mensaje2) gets the value of mensaje1.remote?

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: There is quite a difference between C and C++ here. The code is C-style, no C++ programmer in their right mind would write code like this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but anyone could guess from the code that it's C, like Walter said. Specially for the `typedef` why would you do that in C++?

Comment: @iharob: I wouldn't but I've seen code written by thousands of programmers who did. So that tells us literally zero about the OP's intent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the remainder of this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67571/discussion-on-question-by-keont-two-variables-from-different-structs-give-me-a-c).

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons, arrays cannot be directly copied in C or C++. :(

If you used C++'s `std::array<char, 128>` instead then you'd be able to do it:

```
struct Message
{
   int op;
   std::array<char, 128> local;
   std::array<char, 128> remote;
   int port;
};

int main()
{
   Message mensaje1, mensaje2;
   mensaje1.remote = mensaje2.remote;
}
```

It rather looks like you want a *string*, though; `std::string` are copyable too!

```
struct Message
{
   int op;
   std::string local;
   std::string remote;
   int port;
};

int main()
{
   Message mensaje1, mensaje2;
   mensaje1.remote = mensaje2.remote;
}
```

Otherwise you're going to have to use `std::copy` to copy the array elements manually:

```
struct Message
{
   int op;
   std::string local;
   std::string remote;
   int port;
};

int main()
{
   Message mensaje1, mensaje2;
   std::copy(
      std::begin(mensaje2.remote),
      std::end(mensaje2.remote),
      std::begin(mensaje2.remote)
   );
}
```

The error message you're getting is confusing because the compiler tries, as a last-ditch effort, to use the implicit conversion of an array's name to pointer-to-its-first-element, before finally giving up.

Comment: That part about std::  ... I can't implement it right now, but why would that work? Does that go to a lower level of implementation or...?

Comment: @keont: Which part? I used `std::` in several places.

Comment: Totally my bad, I thought it was some kind of operator. I'm not familiar with that type of expressions at all, are they c++ only, or also for C?

Comment: @keont: I don't know what you're referring to. "That type of expressions". _Specifically_, what are you asking me?

Comment: What do you mean by historical reasons? Put another way: What would be a useful definition of copying semantics for arrays? I don't see any without either dropping array decay at all or defining something like "`array = pointer` means `memcpy(array, pointer, sizeof array)`", which both don't look useful to me at a first glance, and the latter doesn't conflict with existing code, so historic reasons don't apply.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are second class citizens in C, you cannot assign arrays. Use `memcpy` to copy an array or `strcpy / strncpy` to copy a string.

Comment: Arrays are not second-class citizens. It is true that they cannot be directly copied.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit they are and if you don't agree, feel free to post a comment to Steve Summit, maintainer of c-faq: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrkindofary.html

Comment: Consider actually reading that post. He's presenting abstract ways of considering the situation. I do submit that #2 is flat-out wrong and, when I get the time, I shall indeed post a comment to Steve about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in that case also propose an edit to this Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen Most objects in C can be copied using the assignment operator but arrays (among other limitations) cannot, it's a perfect fit for a *second-class citizen* inclusion.

Comment: Mmmmmm.... it makes me itch. But by the definition on that page, I will accept your nomination of arrays as "second-class citizens".

Comment: I downvoted because `strcpy` is batshit insane and `memcpy` and friends are nearly as bad. This is the "Overflow your own buffers" method.

Comment: @Puppy I guess you didn't see that `strncpy` is mentioned in the answer and maybe you are not aware that with `memcpy` you can control the size argument. I hope that your own answers are not downvoted with the same sense of casualness.

Comment: +one, @Puppy What is your alternative to memcpy?

Answer (score 0):

You must copy the contents of one array into the other, use `strcpy`

```
strcpy(mensaje2.remote, mensaje1.remote);
```

Comment: I don't want to compare I want to... I don't know the verb, I want to put the info to the left of the equal. 

But that works so thanks!

Comment: @keont: "Assign", or "copy".

Comment: @keont, if it doesn't bother anyone else, can you write the verb in spanish?

Comment: Don't strcpy anything.

Comment: Yes iharob I've read it, I don't know if I should get a hint with that :S being a long day.

The verb would be asignar. But I would think of assignate or some wrong word like that if I tried to say it in english.

Comment: @keont: "Assign". I've said it a few times.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit exactamente.

Comment: @keont qué es lo que quieres lograr? -> `keont what are you trying to achieve?`

Comment: This was: strcpy(), so that I could get the value of one part of a struct and put it into another struct. Since it's an array it's a problem of C not being able to do that, and I didn't know/remember that so with strcpy I can now get the values without iterating through they whole array. Thanks for all!!

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark below the votes.